# Whose answer should you accept: Another person's or your own?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I asked a question about a programming problem and someone wrote a couple of comments, trying to help me find the source of the problem and even pointing out a problem with my code that was easy to fix (but that wasn't the problem I originally asked the question for).

Eventually that other person suggested a different way of doing what I was trying to do but I ended up fixing the problem within my original code myself. Afterwards I asked the other person to post his suggestion as an answer, which I already upvoted (because it works too) and I'm also going to post an answer explaning how to fix my original code with the solution I found.

Now I'm not sure what to do with those two answers: My answer fixes the code and solves the problem but the other guy's answer works too and he suggested the alternative way of doing it before I was able to fix the code myself.

Which answer do you accept in that case? The answer that came first or the answer that stays true to the original code?

Comment: The problem is: The other guy's answer works too. It's an alternative way of doing what I'm trying to do and in the end it doesn't change the result or even how I call the method. It's just a couple of lines that change with a single method.

Comment: @Neph Definitely consider upvoting the other answer. Typically, accepting the most helpful answer is the correct course of action, but *ultimately,* you can accept whatever answer you want. You're the OP, and the power of answer acceptance rests firmly on your shoulders and no one else's.

Comment: @Spevacus So, what you're saying is: If multiple answers are correct and give you the same result, pick the one from the person who was the most helpful?

Comment: Yes. If you absolutely, truly, undeniably can't decide... Then you don't have to accept one at all. Or, if *none* of the answers help you, then you're under no obligation to accept one.

Comment: @Spevacus I'd like to accept an answer to show that the problem was solved. Unfortunately no. `You choose the answer that solved your problem and worked best for you` - both answers solve my problem and seem to do what I want them to do (I've not noticed any problems with either so far). I was hoping for some unwritten "rule", aka "if it doesn't matter at all, pick the other person's to give them the rep for it" or "pick yours because you fixed it yourself and upvote the other person's".

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no written or unwritten rule for this sort of scenario. I'd refer back to what I said previously, though: "It's up to you." Wanna give the other user some rep for his efforts? Go for it, accept that answer. Maybe even give it an upvote. Definitely hang on to your own answer, though, because you *did* find a solution to your problem, and that deserves to stick around.

Answer (score 5):

> "I ended up fixing the problem within my original code myself"

That is your answer, you should accept the answer that worked for you.

Do not accept an answer just because it is the first, accept the one that is the solution to your problem. Who wrote it, even if it was you, is irrelevant.

> "The problem is: The other guy's answer works too..."

Accepting is supposed to show what answer worked *for you*, not that one is better than another or that one is also correct, that is what votes are for. In this case you clearly state that you fixed the issue with your own solution and that seems like the one to accept but ultimately, the choice is yours alone.

Don't forget you can still upvote the other one if you like it or if you love it, give it a bounty (start at 50 rep) to say thanks.

Comment: `accept the one that is the solution to your problem` - what if both answers work well as a solution and there's no noticeable difference in run time?

Comment: What I mean is the one you used to solve your problem. You say "I ended up fixing the problem within my original code myself" and that is all I am going off of here. You are free to accept the other one, there is no rule for this, it is completely up to you. If you are worried that it might be rude to not accept a working answer in lieu of your own, then don't, any users who regularly answer4 questions will understand. I don't know what else to tell you, it is your choice in the end, we can't tell you exactly what to accept, that is your privilege as OP.

Comment: Tbh, I implemented both (still have both in my code) but ended up using a different/3rd solution (neither the other person's nor mine) because I changed some other code and wanted to try a different way of doing it. I know, this doesn't make the decision easier, that's why I was hoping for some kind of "etiquette rule" but, as Spevacus already said, there's nothing of that kind.

Comment: As unhelpful as it seems, Spevacus is 100% correct, there is no rule or even etiquette for this. Can you link the question in your original post? Someone may see something that could swing it one way or the other.